# Asynchronous Download of Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, request

I am trying to download an image off of a server asynchronously. After the image is downloaded and placed, I then want the app to go to the next view controller with an image view that will contain the image. Here is my code:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://...../.png"]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                                        if ( !error ) {
                                              image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

                                              if (image != NULL) {
                                                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"midnight" sender:self];
                                                               }
                                                       }

                                       NSLog(@"%@", image);
                          }];
    }
```

The problem is that the next view controller will come up with nothing on it for about 10-15 seconds and then show the image and the text that is supposed to be displayed on the view controller. Is there something that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you passing the image you get with this method to the next view controller?

Comment: BTW, your queue should be [NSOperationQueue mainQueue], since you're doing UI related things (the push) in the completion block. I'm surprised that you would even get your push with the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fine for me. I used your code, but changed the operation queue to the mainQueue, and added code to pass the image to the ImageViewController:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ImageViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage *image;
@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)downloadPic:(id)sender {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://atmire.com/labs17/bitstream/handle/123456789/7618/earth-map-huge.jpg?sequence=1"]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                               if ( !error ) {
                                   _image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

                                   if (_image != NULL) {
                                       NSLog(@"Image id: %@", _image);
                                       NSLog(@"Image size is: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(_image.size));
                                       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"midnight" sender:self];
                                   }
                               }else{
                                   NSLog(@"Error is: %@",error);
                               }
                           }];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    ImageViewController *ivc = segue.destinationViewController;
    ivc.receivedImage = _image;
}
```

In the ImageViewController, I created a property, receivedImage, and had just this code:

```
@interface ImageViewController ()
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *iv;
@end

@implementation ImageViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.iv.image = self.receivedImage;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually just realized from @rdelmar that when I changed it to mainQueue it worked. +1

Comment: @Zack, how were you getting your push to work at all before you made that change?

Comment: In the "prepare for segue" I was telling the image on the current view controller to pass through to the next UIImage and then in the view did load of the destination controller to load the UIImage into a UIImageView. Technically it was able to work because I am getting a value back from the request and transferring the data over to the destination view controller. Hope this makes a little bit of sense!

Comment: @Zack, that doesn't explain why the segue was performed at all. When I tried your code using [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init], I never got the segue because it wasn't being called on the main thread. Were you doing something else to get the segue to go?